# Numerical Integration, error bound setting step size.

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I have been trying to find another solution to the problem pointed out (hopefully) in the title of this question. I am solving some simple numerical integration in order to practice. For example this one (using trapezoidal integration).
$$ \int_{0.5}^{1}\cos(\sqrt{x}\,)\,dx $$
where, i know that
$$|E_{total}|=\frac{h^2(1-0.5)}{12}\,|f''(\xi)|\quad \text{where} \quad \xi\,\in\,[0.5\,,\,1]  $$

So I would like to know if there is any way to determine the stepsize (such that the error is less or equal to (insert error bound here)) other than maximizing the modulus of the second derivative of x, analyzing the nasty third derivative.

i.e. $$ |f''(\xi)|\leq M $$ $$\frac{h^2}{24}\,|f''(\xi)|\leq \frac{h^2}{24}\,M\leq10^{-3} $$

Comment: The bound you state is the best a priori error bound for numerical integration. You could of course use an adaptive quadrature routine which dynamically changes the resolution of your integration based on the concavity. You could also evaluate the integral with two separate step sizes and estimate the error to leading order accuracy using [Richardson Extrapolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson_extrapolation)

Comment: I'm not sure that your function $\cos\sqrt x=1-\frac12 x+\frac1{24}x^2-\frac1{6!}^3\pm\dots$ is that bad over the interval that adaptive quadrature will make much of a difference. So the reason for the question is that the symbolic second derivative looks a little complicated?

Comment: It's easy to show that $\displaystyle\frac1{12}\sin1\le f''(x)\le\frac1{12}$ for $x\in[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

$$f'(x)=-\frac{\sin\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{x}}=-\frac12\int^1_0\cos(\sqrt{x}t)\,dt,$$
so
$$f''(x)=\frac14\int^1_0t\,\frac{\sin(\sqrt{x}t)}{\sqrt{x}}\,dt\tag1.$$
$\sin u$ is concave on $[0,1]$, so $$u\,\sin 1\le\sin u\le u$$ for $u\in[0,1]$. Using this (with $u=\sqrt{x}t$) in (1), we arrive at
$$\frac14\int^1_0t^2\,\sin 1\,dt\le f''(x)\le\frac14\int^1_0t^2\,dt,$$ i.e.
$$\frac1{12}\,\sin 1\le f''(x)\le\frac1{12}.$$
To get a sharp estimate from below, we could observe that from (1), we can conclude that $f''(x)$ is monotone decreasing, so $\displaystyle f''(x)\ge f''(1)=\frac{\sin1-\cos1}4$.

Comment: LutzL Thanks for pointing that out, I've corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

For $f(x)=\cos\sqrt x$, $f'(x)=-\frac{\sin\sqrt x}{2\sqrt x}$ the second derivative is
$$
f''(x)=-\frac{\cos\sqrt{x}}{4x}+\frac{\sin\sqrt x}{4\sqrt x^3}
=\frac{\sin^2(\sqrt x/2))}{2x}-\frac1{4x}\left(1-\frac{\sin\sqrt x}{\sqrt x}\right)
$$
By the alternating nature of the sine series, for $|u|<2\sqrt5$
$$
1\ge\frac{\sin u}{u}\ge 1-\frac16u^2
$$
so that for $|x|\le 2$
$$
|f''(x)|\le \frac18+\frac1{24}=\frac16.
$$